# I don't understand how to walk through the array

Tags: assembly, timer, x86, x86-16, masm

I want to loop through an array of **duration** numbers using the **si** register. But it doesn't work out right for me. If I pass only one number **dur**, then it works fine, if I want to iterate, then it freezes and nothing else. Explain the error. Thanks!

```
sseg    segment stack
        db      256 dup(?)
sseg    ends
dseg    segment
    music       dw  4063, 2559, 3835
    duration    dd  270000, 360000, 180000
    dur         dd 270000
    len         dw  3
dseg    ends
cseg    segment
        assume ss:sseg,cs:cseg,ds:dseg
start:  jmp main
main:   push    ds
        xor     ax,ax
        push    ax
        mov     ax,dseg
        mov     ds,ax
        cli
        ;------------------------------
        xor     di,di
        xor     si,si
cycle:
        mov     al,10110110b
        out     43h,al
        
        in      al,61h
        or      al,3
        out     61h,al
        ;------------
        mov     ax,music[si]
        out     42h,al
        mov     al,ah
        out     42h,al

        les     dx,dur      ;duratin[si]
        mov     cx,es
        mov     ah,86h
        int     15h
        ;------------
        in      al,61h
        and     al,11111100b
        out     61h,al
        ;------------
        inc     si
        inc     di
        cmp     si,len
        jnae    cycle
        ;------------------------------
exit:
        sti
        mov     ax,4c00h
        int     21h     
cseg    ends
        end start
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Which instruction are you talking about?  Can you explain precisely in words what you want / expect that instruction to do?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the MASM syntax for a base + offset addressing mode is not `music[si]` but rather `[music+si]`.

Comment: Can you run this code, but change dur to duration[si]?

Comment: I don't have the tools handy to assemble and run this, sorry.  But as I mentioned, I think it ought to be `[duration+si]` instead.  I would suspect the `music` is also getting ignored in `music[si]` and only happens to work because `music` is at offset 0 in your data segment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through an array in NASM assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619604/iterating-through-an-array-in-nasm-assembly-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov     ax,music[si]
> ```

Whether MASM allows `music[si]` or `[music+si]` is of no real importance in next discussion.

The important point is that the `SI` register is not an array index like we know from the high level languages, but rather **it is an offset from the start of the array and always measured in bytes**.
Therefore in your program you need to add 2 to the register that addresses the *music* array (words), and you need to add 4 to the register that addresses the *duration* array (dwords).

```
    music       dw  4063, 2559, 3835
    duration    dd  270000, 360000, 180000
    len = $-offset duration

    ...

    xor     di, di           ; Offset in duration array
    xor     si, si           ; Offset in music array
cycle:
    ...
    mov     ax, music[si]
    ...
    les     dx, duration[di] ; This is DI, beware of your typo
    mov     cx, es
    mov     ah, 86h
    int     15h
    ...
    add     si, 2            ; To next music item (word=2)
    add     di, 4            ; To next duration item (dword=4)
    cmp     di, len
    jb      cycle
```